# Extract zip files contents and rename the directory dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unzip, directory-structure

I have an application zip file created using Play Framework. It create the zip file with name A-1.0.zip. This zip file contains the directory with name A-1.0. (1.0 changes according to the version)

I wanted to extract the zip file and rename the folder from A-1.0 to A. So that my application init.d script finds the directory to start the application. This shuld be done dynamically using shell script.

Is there a way where i can extract all the zip files into A folder instead of extracting into A-1.0 and renaming?? Please help!

The following is what I tried....

```
unzip A-1.0.zip -d ~/A
```

(I know that it is very dumb of me to do this !!)

This extracted the file into `~/A/A-1.0/[contents]`

I need to extract all the [contents] into `~/A` instead of `~/A/A-1.0/`. I dunno how to do this using command line.....

My init.d script searched for `~/A/bin/A -Dhttp.port=6565 -Dconfig.file=~/A/conf/application.conf` to start the Play! application.

To make this script working, I extract all into A-1.0/ then I rename with `mv ~/A-1.0 ~/A` manually.

Comment: While this is possible, this question does not show any coding effort. Appears to be requesting code writing service which in not what SO is for. Please update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: hope I have given what I tried. Sorry for not updating the what I did in the first place...

Comment: A simple `unzip --help` discloses using `unzip -d ~/A -j A-1.0.zip` may do exactly what you want. (test it -- I did not verify, just read)

Comment: The command given removes all the folder structure in the zip file and extracts only the contentes into the A folder.

Comment: @Rankin: Using -j flattens the directory structure. So it only works if you have no subdirectories, or your really want all files in one directory.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find any specific unzip option to perform this automatically, but managed to achieve this goal by creating a temporary symbolic link in order to artificially redirect the extracted files this way

```
ln -s A A-1.0
unzip A-1.0.zip
rm A-1.0
```

Comment: Although it would be nicer if unzip had an option (similar to tar --transform), this approach did work for me and can be used with unzip -o (overwrite). This serves me better than mv because for mv the destination folder must not exist.

Answer (score 2):

From the [unzip man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) it boils down to:

```
unzip A-1.0.zip 'A-1.0/*' -d /the/output/dir
      ^         ^
      |         |
      |         +- files to extract (note the quotes: unzip shall parse the wildcard instd of sh)
      +- The archive
```

Comment: It is not working. This just extracts all contents into ~/A/. The directory looks like this after extraction ~/A/A-1.0/[contents]

Comment: Scary story... i'll give it a try when i'm near my linux box

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer does **not preserve subdirectories**. It works fine if one doesn't have or need the subdirectory structure.

I found that you can combine the answer from @géza-török with the `-j` option mentioned by @david-c-rankin (in the comment below the question). Which leads to `unzip -j A-1.0.zip 'A-1.0/*' -d /the/output/dir`. That would only process the files inside A-1.0/ and output them straight into the given output directory.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip (look at -j)

Comment: This doesn't preserve the directory structure below `A-1.0`

Comment: You are right, it you need to preserve the directory structure that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to unzip all .zip files in the current directory into directories with names of the zip files (even after you rename them)

the following command is not elegant but works

```
cd to/the/dir
find *.zip | cut -d. -f1 | xargs -I % sh -c "unzip %.zip -d %; ls % | xargs -I @ sh -c 'mv %/@/* %; rm -rf %/@'"
```